# PHP strpos() returning odd results

Tags: php, security, loops

I've written a basic 'security checker' for my webapp. I'll need to see at a glance whether user-submitted code contains evil stuff.

**Here is a screenshot** of the code that I'm running this against right now: http://cl.ly/677a6dc40034f096697f

**Here is the PHP code** I'm using against these three bits of code:

```
<!-- The View -->
<h2>Security analysis</h2>
<?php echo securitycheck($html, $css, $js); ?>
```

-

```
// The controller
function securitycheck($html, $css, $js)
{
    // The code is the html, css, and js, appended together. We're scanning it all.
    $code = $html." ".$css." ".$js;

    // $insecure is our array of naughty things to search for.
    $insecure = array(
                        /* HTML Elements */
                        'applet',
                        'basefont',
                        'base',
                        'behavior',
                        'bgsound',
                        'blink',
                        'embed',
                        'expression',
                        'frameset',
                        'frame',
                        'ilayer',
                        'iframe',
                        'isindex',
                        'javascript',
                        'layer',
                        'link',
                        'meta',
                        'object',
                        'plaintext',
                        'style',
                        'script',
                        'xml',
                        'xss',
                        /* Javascript Elements */
                        'alert',
                        'cmd',
                        'passthru',
                        'eval',
                        'exec',
                        'expression',
                        'system',
                        'fopen',
                        'fromcharcode',
                        'fsockopen',
                        'file',
                        'file_get_contents',
                        'readfile',
                        'unlink',
                        /* Misc Elements */
                        'vbscript:',
                        '<?',
                        '<?php',
                        '?>'
                    );

    $found = "";
    $output = "<p><strong>Potentially insecure items found:</strong> ";

    foreach($insecure as $item)
    {
        if (($pos = strpos($code, $item)) !== FALSE)
        {
            $found .= "$item, ";
        }
    }

    if ($found == "")
    {
        $output .= "None.<br/>";
    }
    else
    {
        $output .= "<span class=\"alert\">".substr($found, 0, -2)."</span>"."</p><br/>";  // cuts trailing comma and space from $found
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Finally, **here is a screenshot of the returned output (in HTML)**: http://cl.ly/f246dc419fb499dd6bd7

See the screenshot? There are several things wrong. The trailing space and comma haven't been cut off (which I used `substr()` to do, and also it's reporting two `alert`s when as you can see from the first screenshot, there's only one been run through this.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Jack

**EDIT:** As Fosco kindly pointed out, `alert` was listed twice in my array (doh!). I've fixed that, however the problem of the trailing comma be left is still there. I know this is a smaller issue but I swear it still shouldn't be there...

Comment: alert is listed twice in your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a glance your code looks like it should give the output you want. I am not sure what is going wrong.

Instead of building `$found` as a string, I would recommend constructing it as an array and then using `implode()` to get a string:

- replace `$found = "";` with `$found = array();`
- replace `$found .= "$item, ";` with `$found[] = $item;`

and replace this block of code:

```
if ($found == "")
{
    $output .= "None.<br/>";
}
else
{
    $output .= "<span class=\"alert\">".substr($found, 0, -2)."</span>"."</p><br/>";  // cuts trailing comma and space from $found
}
```

with this:

```
if (!count($found))
{
    $output .= "None.<br/>";
}
else
{
    $output .= "<span class=\"alert\">".implode(', ',$found)."</span>"."</p><br/>";  // cuts trailing comma and space from $found
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hammerite, I'm now doing this as an array, I guess that's a better idea! Only problem is - it's still outputting it with a trailing comma after `eval,` as @Joseph said it might be something to do with `<?php` - I'm going to edit the code manually and have a look into that.

Comment: I see. But banning should be done with caution... User can just paste HTML from somewhere being unaware of it's contents.

Comment: @FractalizeR the subject of the site is one for *original* CSS3, HTML5, and JS snippets. Anything which triggers a security warning I pay extra close attention to. obviously if it looks like a blatantly deliberate hacking attempt they get banned, if it's just a copy-paste mistake a polite email is sent asking them to revise their submission.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way of dealing with the found items would be to use...

```
$found = array();

foreach($insecure as $item)
{
    if (($pos = strpos($code, $item)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $found[] $item;
    }
}
$found = implode(', ', $found);
```

And there's only one alert in the string, but it in your $insecure list twice, hence the fact it appears in the output twice. To avoid that you would have to scan each section separately.

Comment: thanks very much! I saw the second alert and that's been removed, and am now using this array() method.

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel.

http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: Thanks @FractalizeR, I'm not reinventing the wheel - I'm actually going to be using HTML Purifier when I need to output this 'live' to users. This is purely an at-a-glance way to see if users have been inserting bad stuff, so I can see whether further precautions (e.g. banning) need to take place.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just echoing $found and then doing a View Source?  I will guess that the issue is that one of your items is not being displayed based on HTML encoding ('`<?`') and that there is a comma and space that actually is being removed.

But I will echo @Hammerite with his solutions.

Comment: you were right, it was the outputting of `<?` that was breaking it. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Use htmlentities to encode it before displaying it onscreen: `htmlentities(substr($found, 0, -2))` -- http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php